# processing non english text is too slow on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS application which is necessary to process non english text, however functions that work for english text properly, dont work for other languages. for example

```
CGRect labelRect = [text
                    boundingRectWithSize:size
                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                    attributes:@{
                                 NSFontAttributeName : font
                                 }
                    context:nil];
```

takes a long time to calculate the proper size for non english texts and other possible functions are the same.

I was wondering if any one could help me.

Comment: no one knows???